# Fundamental solution to $\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}x^2}=I(x)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, convolution, greens-function, fundamental-solution

Here, $I(x)$ is the indicator function on the interval ([0,1]) (i.e. $I(x)=1$ if $x\in [0,1]$ and $0$ otherwise).

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_solution#An_example_that_more_clearly_works), we can find the fundamental solution $F(x)=\frac{|x|}{2}$ and then take its convolution with $I(x)$ to find a solution $f(x)$. Thus far, I understand.

What I don't get is how to differentiate that convolution twice in order to get $I(x)$. Here's my attempt:
\begin{align*}(I*F)(x)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(x-y)I(y)\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{|x-y|}{2}\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\left[\frac{y}{4}(2x-y)\mathrm{sign}(x-y)\right]_0^1\\
&=\frac{1}{4}(2x-1)\text{sign}(x-1).
\end{align*}

Thing is, if I differentiate this twice, don't I just get $0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand the step where you integrate; instead, I'd do
\begin{align*}
  \int_{0}^{1} \frac{|x - y|}{2}\, dy
  &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} |y - x|\, dy
  = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-x}^{1-x} |y|\, dy \\
  &= \frac{y|y|}{4}\bigg|_{-x}^{1-x}
  = \frac{(1 - x)|1 - x| + x|x|}{4}
  = \frac{x|x| - (x - 1)|x - 1|}{4},
\end{align*}
which checks.